# android could not connect to ftp host

Tags: android

i am using the  [ftpclient](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=139) library and followed their example to make a simple ftp client app, my problem is when trying to connect :

```
try {
   mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
   // connecting to the host
   mFTPClient.connect(host, port);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Log.d("", "Error: could not connect to host " + host);
}
```

i rechecked my ip and port and nothing wrong, i even downloaded an ftp app "ftpcafe" to check if the problem wasnt from my code it worked fine, * note that i added the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

do i need more permissions? and what is going on? and one last thing when i used ftpcafe app it didnt prompt me to enter port number while its is needed in my code, can someone explain this as i am new to network programming thing?

Comment: There is a default port for FTP, it's 21. Try also to look at some exaples about FTP on android like this http://androidjayavelu.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/android-connect-to-ftp-server-example.html

Comment: After the line mFTPClient.connect(host, port) add boolean login = mFTPClient.login(sUserName, sPassword) (with your corresponding user name and password) and check the status of the boolean login variable. How is it?

Comment: i already have a login in the try block but exception is caught on mFTPClient.connect()

Comment: Same problem for me! If i run my app in the emulator, it's all right. But when I run it on a LG P350, Android 2.2, I get a SocketException when connecting. The only difference I can guess between phone and emulator is that I'm using phone's WiFi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try without port (if port 21).

```
mFTPClient.connect(host);
```

You may have some information about the problem in the exception ?

```
Log.d("",e.getMessage());
```

Comment: i tried the mFTPClient.connect(host); still the same prob and  e.getMessage() returns null :( have i missed a permission?